# Select radio button should not select entire row on md-data-table angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I have the data table and when I select a radio button, the entire table row gets selected.
below is my code

[image]

Expectation:

When I select the radio button it should not select the table row.
[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/nt7UAxdB4M7lhQiM)
could someone help me on this

```html
  <md-data-table-container>
               <table md-data-table md-row-select="testConfig.selected">
                  <thead md-trim-column-names md-order="testConfig.order">
                     <tr>
                        <th order-by="name">Report Name</th>
                        <th numeric order-by="views.value">Visits</th>
                        <th numeric order-by="users.value">Unique Users</th>
                        <th>Users</th>
                     </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody md-auto-select>
                     <tr ng-repeat="report in test_data | orderBy: testConfig.order">
                        <td>{{report.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{report.views.value}}</td>
                        <td>{{report.users.value}}</td>
                        <td>
                           <ul>
                              <li ng-repeat="person in people">
                                 <label>
                                 <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.name" name="name" value="{{person.name}}" required />{{person.name}}
                                 </label>
                              </li>
                           </ul>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </md-data-table-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on `label` of radio button, to prevent the `click` event propagation to the table row:

```
<md-data-table-container>
   <table md-data-table md-row-select="testConfig.selected">
      <thead md-trim-column-names md-order="testConfig.order">
         <tr>
            <th order-by="name">Report Name</th>
            <th numeric order-by="views.value">Visits</th>
            <th numeric order-by="users.value">Unique Users</th>
            <th>Users</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody md-auto-select>
         <tr ng-repeat="report in test_data | orderBy: testConfig.order">
            <td>{{report.name}}</td>
            <td>{{report.views.value}}</td>
            <td>{{report.users.value}}</td>
            <td>
               <ul>
                  <li ng-repeat="person in people">
                     <label ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
                     <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.name" name="name" value="{{person.name}}" required />{{person.name}}
                     </label>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</md-data-table-container>
```